# problem with spaces in a sorted dictionary with lambda

Tags: python, sorting

I have a nested dictionary. I want to sort it firstly by points, secondly by wins ( if points are the same) and lastly by alphabet if wins is equal. At the end I must have the result exactly like :

```
    Spain  wins:1 , loses:0 , draws:2 , goal difference:2 , points:5
Iran  wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4
Portugal  wins:1 , loses:1 , draws:1 , goal difference:0 , points:4
Morocco  wins:1 , loses:2 , draws:0 , goal difference:-2 , points:3
```

My problem is with the space between wins,loses,...with the scorces. mine is like :wins: 1 but it must be wins:1 without any space.
Here is my code:

```
dic={"Iran":{"wins":1,"loses":1,"draws":1,"goal difference":0,"points":4},{"Spain":{"wins":1,"loses":0,"draws":2,"goal difference":2,"points":5}},{"Portugal":{"wins":1,"loses":1,"draws":1,"goal difference":0,"points":4}},{"Morocco":{"wins":1,"loses":2,"draws":0,"goal difference":-2,"points":3}}}
sort_data=sorted(dic.keys(),key=lambda x:(-dic[x]["points"],dic[x]["wins"]))
for items in sort_data:
    x=dic[items]
    print(items," ",str(x).replace("'", "").replace("{","").replace("}", ""))
```

all is correct except the space in my output which is like:

```
Iran  wins: 1, loses: 1, draws: 1 , goal difference: 0, points: 4
Portugal  wins: 1, loses: 1, draws: 1, goal difference: 0, points: 4
Morocco  wins: 1, loses: 2, draws: 0, goal difference: -2, points: 3
```

Comment: You could replace `","` with `" ,"` and `": "` with `":"` to get the spaces correct. But it might be better to use a proper format-string instead of just converting the dicts to strings and changing some details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add some more `replace` calls, replacing `","` with `" ,"` and `": "` with `":"` to add the spaces before commas, and remove those after colons. Note that your code would print three spaces after the country name, though, since another space in added as the separator between all things to be printed. Use `sep=""` to fix that.

```
for item in sort_data:
    print(item, "  ", str(dic[item]).replace("'", "").replace("{","").replace("}", "")
                                   .replace(",", " ,").replace(": ", ":"), sep="")
```

Alternatively, you could use a format-string to properly format the different key-value pairs in the way you like and then `join` those together with `" , "`:

```
for item in sort_data:
    print(item, " , ".join(f"{k}:{v}" for k, v in dic[item].items()), sep="  ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `print` with multiple arguments joins them with a space. Use either string concatenation or string formatting instead:

```
A = "aa"
B = "bb"
print(A, B)
# Prints 'aa bb'
print(A + B)
# Prints 'aabb'
print(f"{A}{B}")
# Prints 'aabb'
```

Comment: I could not solve the problem. Could you please help me more?

Comment: `print(items," ",str(x).replace("'", "").replace("{","").replace("}", ""))` this is putting extra spaces because you use `print(A, B, C, ...)`, you need to replace it with one of the other options where you put your string together and pass it as 1 thing to `print`: `total = A + B; print(total)`